# How to make a complete page with links and images in css

Tags: css, templates

I would like to make a template in css of a complete page, together with links and images, so that I can just change the nav bar of the template once only, and have it change on every page. I have searched for weeks and can't find out how to do this. I would like to rewrite my whole website using just this one template, because each time I want to add or change  a link, I must go into all 200 pages...

Comment: I'm not sure CSS is the right answer to your problem, since it deals with style, not markup. Server-side includes / master pages / client-side templates seem to be more suited to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Frederic. I'm not sure that I know what Server-side includes / master pages etc. are though (I am fairly new to this). However, I will search and see if I can find details on these. Thanks for giving me the name of what to look for...